# Sending hex values through a BluetoothLE connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a novice in android development, so please forgive if the descriptions are not totally correct.

I am using the Android BTLE example app as a template and am attempting to send simple hex values to a Microchip RN4020 module. I can successfully send data (specifically time data using the calendar function) and they appear on my PuTTY window. However the problem is that the data is being 'transmitted' from the application (on my Samsung j5) as an ASCII representation.... in other words, the Calendar function returns the minute as say 20 (20hex = 32 decimal), which is somehow ending up as ASCII 20 on my PuTTY terminal (i.e. 32 30).

I am sending the data as a Byte array, which as I understand it constrains the range of values to be -127 to +127. So to combat this I have attempted to break the value into upper and lower nibbles and send these as separate bytes.....same problem. The value appearing is the ASCII 2 0....(i.e. 32 30).

I have taken the liberty of posting below my code (apologies for the 'clunkiness' of it). I strongly suspect it is a really rudimentary error, but I cant find how to transmit the 'hex values' Please help

regards

J

```
public void onClickTest(View v){
    if(mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        //Data_1[0] =  (Integer.toHexString((byte)calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) & 0xFF));   //Alarm Set
        int temp = 0;
        int temp1 = 0;
        byte first = 0;
        byte second = 0;
        temp = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        temp1 = temp;
        temp = temp & 0xf0;
        temp = temp >> 4;
        temp1 = temp1 & 0x0f;
        first = (byte)temp;
        second = (byte)temp1;
        Data_1[0] = first;
        Data_1[1] = second;   //Alarm Set
        //Data_1[1] = 0xff;   //Update clock
       // Data_1[2] = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
       // Data_1[2] = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
       // Data_1[3] = (char)calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
       // Data_1[4] = (char)calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       // Data_1[5] = (byte)calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
       // Data_1[6] = (byte)calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       // Data_1[7] = (byte)calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        //myArray = (Arrays.toString(Data_1));

        mBluetoothLeService.writeCustomCharacteristicString(Data_1);
```

This is the actual LE service bit

```
public void writeCustomCharacteristicString(byte[] value) {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
        return;
    }
    /*check if the service is available on the device*/
    BluetoothGattService mCustomService1 = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("12345678-9012-3456-7890-1234567890FF"));
    if(mCustomService1 == null){
        Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
        return;
    }
    /*get the read characteristic from the service*/
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic1 = mCustomService1.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789011"));

    mWriteCharacteristic1.setValue(value);
    if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic1) == false){
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to write characteristic");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a Bluetooth problem. If calendar.get returns 0x20, Data_1[0] will be 0x02 and Data_1[1] will be 0x00. This will also be sent via BLE as byte array. So I assume that the problem is on the receiving side when this array is translated back to an ASCII string. Can you check what the microchip does with the received data? Or is it a blackbox you can't access?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I was more interested to ensure that my Android code was at least partially correct. I have read the data for the module a number of times and my understanding is still a little hazy. But I think what it is now saying (as it always has!!) is that all data to control the characteristics is in ASCII. I rather assumed this was the instructions and control parameters, but now I believe this also means the data - as this is the characteristic of the service (forgive the loose terminology). In essence the 'data' will be in ASCII.

Comment: Also I have now written a short routine that translates the ASCII characters (there are only 16 of interest) into the 'hex' values I need. Any thoughts others have on this issue would be good and might serve as help for others using the RN4020. J